# How to make custom NPC eggs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How would you make a spawn egg with custom NPCs in Minecraft? For instance, an egg that spawns Herobrine (a new NPC that dosen't exist in the base game).

Comment: Are you looking to just spawn an existing mob with the name "Herobrine" or are you looking for a NPC that doesn't exist in the base game?

Comment: A new NPC that doesn't exist in the base game.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to download a mod. Otherwise you would have to put a new sprite in the spritesheets, then edit the item tables to include it.

Comment: You may want to give this another edit as the question has changed, though this still seems to be the correct answer.